# Auto update with script file with transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to provide an auto update feature to my application. 
I am having problem in applying the SQL updates. I have the updated SQL statement in my .sql file and what i want to achieve is that if one statment fails then entire script file must be rolled back
Ex.

```
create procedure [dbo].[test1]        
@P1 varchar(200),        
@C1 int        
as        
begin 
Select 1
end

GO

Insert into test (name) values ('vv')

Go

alter procedure [dbo].[test2]        
@P1 varchar(200),        
@C1 int        
as        
begin 
Select 1
end

GO
```

Now in the above example, if i get the error in third statement of "alter procedure [dbo].[test2]" then i want to rollback the first two changes also which is creating SP of "test1" and inserting data into "test" table

How should i approach this task? Any help will be much appreciated.

If you need any more info then let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you would want to add a `BEGIN TRAN` at the beginning, remove the `GO` statements, and then handle the `ROLLBACK TRAN`/`COMMIT TRAN` with a `TRY..CATCH` block.

When dealing with DML though there are often statements that have to be at the start of a batch, so you can't wrap them in a `TRY..CATCH` block. In that case you need to put together a system that knows how to roll itself back.

A simple system would be just to backup the database at the start and restore it if anything fails (assuming that you are the only one accessing the database the whole time). Another method would be to log each batch that runs successfully and to have corresponding rollback scripts which you can run to put everything back should a later batch fail. This obviously requires much more work (writing an undo script for every script PLUS fully testing the rollbacks) and can also be a problem if people are still accessing the database while the upgrade is happening.

**EDIT:**
Here's an example of a simple `TRY..CATCH` block with transaction handling:

```
BEGIN TRY

BEGIN TRANSACTION

-- All of your code here, with `RAISERROR` used for any of your own error conditions

COMMIT TRANSACTION

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH
```

However, the `TRY..CATCH` block cannot span batches (maybe that's what I was thinking of when I said transactions couldn't), so in your case it would probably be something more like:

```
IF (OBJECT_ID('dbo.Error_Happened') IS NOT NULL)
    DROP TABLE dbo.Error_Happened
GO

BEGIN TRANSACTION

<Some line of code>

IF (@@ERROR <> 0)
    CREATE TABLE dbo.Error_Happened (my_id INT)

IF (OBJECT_ID('dbo.Error_Happened') IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    <Another line of code>

    IF (@@ERROR <> 0)
        CREATE TABLE dbo.Error_Happened (my_id INT)
END

...

IF (OBJECT_ID('dbo.Error_Happened) IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    DROP TABLE dbo.Error_Happened
END
ELSE
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Unfortunately, because of the separate batches from the `GO` statements you can't use `GOTO`, you can't use the `TRY..CATCH`, and you can't persist a variable across the batches. This is why I used the very kludgy trick of creating a table to indicate an error.

A better way would be to simply have an error table and look for rows in it. Just keep in mind that your `ROLLBACK` will remove those rows at the end as well.

Comment: A transaction can span batches.

Comment: Huh. Not sure why I thought that they couldn't. Thanks for pointing that out. I've removed that part of my answer. I think that the rest is still relevant though.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions here. 
My database is kind of huge so i will not prefer the backup/restore. The second way is sound better to me of making rollback statement of each executed SQL. Can you tell me how can i achieve it using the above example. 
Many thanks.